# Send the password through stdin in `ssh-copy-id`

Tags: ssh, pipe, key-authentication

I need to automate some identity deployments, ideally using `ssh-copy-id`.

I'm trying to provide the password through stdin, which is possible on `ssh` by using the `-S` flag. I'm aware that I can send additional options to `ssh` using the `-o` flag in the `ssh-copy-id` command however there's no usage examples of this flag in the man page.

So I've tried to pass the SSH password for `ssh-copy-id` through stdin using:

```
$# echo $TMP_PASS | ssh-copy-id -p2222 -i key.pub user@host -o "-S"
```

But all I get is:

```
/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: -s
```

#### EDIT:

> I'm trying to provide the password through stdin, which is possible on
>   `ssh` by using the `-S` flag.

This statement is wrong. I've actually read this flag from `sudo` man;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might want to try installing sshpass, and altering your call to `ssh-copy-id`:

```
sshpass -p "$TMP_PASS" ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Comment: lol, not on mac and when `brew install` is attempted, i get "Error: No available formula with the name "sshpass" 
We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
ruin SSH's security."

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find the information about `-S` option? It does something completely different! It is used for multiplexing and ControlPath.

SSH will not accept passwords on stdin **ever**, so you should pre-install authorized keys in your deployment (preferred way) or use `sshpass` or `expect` script as described in many other questions.

Comment: Damn you're right! I've just realized that `-S` flag is from `sudo` :S

Comment: If I want to install my keys on 100 hosts, using ssh-copy-id, having that all the hosts already have a default username and password, how to avoid ssh-copy-id asking me every time the same password?

Comment: That is already answered in both of the answers -- use sshpass if you have to or some expect script.

Answer (score 1):

2020 / Mac OS X (copy pasted my answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64734960/10798643))

Install sshpass [(original answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623099/10798643)

```bsh
brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass
```

Run ssh-copy-id using sshpass and with the password as an arg

```bsh
sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh-copy-id -i ~/PATH/TO/KEY $USER@$HOST -p $PORT
```

If you want to turn off strict host checking as well, use the `-o` flag, which is passed to the underlying ssh:

```bsh
sshpass -p hunter2 ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/PATH/TO/KEY $USER@$HOST -p $PORT
```

I tried the solution by @redneb, and installed `setsid` through util-linux by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769823/10798643), but kept receiving a password denied.

I found this strategy to work for uploading my SSH key while setting up multiple raspberry pis in successino. In my script, I also run `ssh-keygen -R raspberrypi.local` each time too, to avoid the `The ECDSA host key for raspberrypi.local has changed` error.