# run script remotely and use result locally with ssh auto login

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote, file-copy, autologin

I want to connect from ServerA to ServerB , and check Oracle Database Status and PendingLogs then record results, and use the result on ServerA ,and compare with the result on serverA and generate logs on serverA.

I used `ssh -q root@192.168.11.131 sh -s < /root/script.sh > /root/output.txt`

but I still have to enter password manually.

1. is there any way to turn off interactive login?
2. how can I run script file via `spawn ssh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- is there any way to turn off interactive login?

Yes, use public key authentication or [`sshpass` to enter password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230084/send-the-password-through-stdin-in-ssh-copy-id/230089#230089).

> 2- how can I run script file via spawn ssh ?

Yes, use [`expect` script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223491/piping-a-password-located-in-a-file-to-the-ssh-command/223520#223520). If you want to run some other script inside (`awk`), you need to escape the special characters (`\$`).

Comment: Then you have the other two options described in my answer.

Comment: we are not authorize to use Public key Authentication , and `sshpass -f /path/to/myfile ssh user@localhost` is not working on CentOS. I used expect , but in my commands I have Awk and it doesn't support.

Comment: you need to specify why it does not work. Probably you just need to install it? In the `expect`, it should not matter. You use it only to connect to the server, not to run any other tools (`awk`).

Comment: you're right sshpass wasn't install. after installation sshpass problem solved. but we are not authorize to install and use this package. About AWK I found following format to use awk in expect. and it worked!! #set cmd "df -h | grep /dev/sda1 | exec awk '\{ print \$4\}'\r"
send $cmd

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for the first question, you may not need to turn off the interactive login but as given by [Jakuje](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/121504/jakuje), you can use sshpass or public key authentication as described in [my blog](https://chamaradisanayake.blogspot.com/2011/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without.html) . Another good reference for public key authentication is available [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/#.TsIsWSn7fUg.blogger).
The sshpass can be used with following format but initially sshpass needs to be installed to your system.

**Command format:**

```
sshpass -f password_file ssh user_login@ip_address_of_the_server
```